# Jquery loop within a var

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am hoping that somebody can help me I have a jquery function which is getting values from a php form and I need to create variable for an ajax call. Is it possible to add a loop within a var

Here is my code so hopefully will explain better what I am trying to do

```
...
var teacher_ids = $( '#teacher_ids' ).val();
var status = 'pending';
var array = teacher_ids.split(','); 

var data = {
  name: title,
  short_description: excerpt,
  description: content,
  status: status,
  type: 'variable',
  variations : [
```

This is where I am having the issue, I have multiple values which I want to be able to loop though

```
$.each(array,function (i, item) {
    variation_type = item.split('_'); 
    {
      regular_price: half_hour,
        attributes: [{
          id:3,
          slug: 'pa_lessonduration',
          //name: 'lessonduration',
          option: '1-hour'
        },{
          id: 1,
          slug: 'pa_weekday',
          //  name: 'weekday',
          option: variation_type[0]
        },{
          id: 2,
          slug: 'pa_daytime',
          //name: 'daytime',
          option: variation_type[1],
        }]
       //"expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression?" 
    }
    //"expected ( saw { "
    })

$.ajax({
        method: "PUT",
        url: POST_SUBMITTER.root + 'wc/v1/products/'+ product_id +'',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', POST_SUBMITTER.nonce );
        },
        success : function( response ) {
            console.log( response );
            alert( POST_SUBMITTER.success );
        },
        fail : function( response ) {
            console.log( response );
            alert( POST_SUBMITTER.failure );
        }


    });
```

Any suggestion on how to get this to work please.   This should print the following but I get errors

```
var data = {
    name: title,
    short_description: excerpt,
    description: content,
    status: status,
    type: 'variable',
    variations: [{
        regular_price: '19.99',
        attributes: [{
            id: 3,
            name: 'pa_lessonduration',
            option: '1-hour'
        }, {
            name: 'pa_daytime',
            option: '0900'
        }, {
            name: 'weekday',
            option: 'monday'
        }]
    },
    {
        regular_price: '19.99',
        attributes: [{
            id: 3,
            name: 'pa_lessonduration',
            option: '1-hour'
        }, {
            name: 'pa_daytime',
            option: '1100'
        }, {
            name: 'weekday',
            option: 'wednesday'
        }]
    }]
}
```

etc etc...

I hope that makes sense, if not ask and I will try to make it more clear

Comment: Thanks for your words of encouragement :) I guess someone like yourself with vast expertise can't comment to aid such a lowly being as my self ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question fully. At first glance, seems to me it would be easier to create the variable for "variations" and then use it, as opposed to trying to create it in place. Would need more info to really understand.

Comment: Thanks Zakarai for tidying my code, sorry I added it on my phone so difficult to get formatting correct, apologies if my format offended I will the whole function once I am in front of my computer to avoid upsetting anyone else

Comment: When asking a question regarding code that isn't doing what you expect it to do and/or is throwing errors. you *must* include the error message, what it is doing, and what you expected it to do. you've only done one of the three.

Comment: @Martiniboy it wasn't a comment about you or your abilities, it was a comment about how this is a symptom of a larger issue; when new programmers jump into bed with a library or a framework without understanding basic programming concepts. You should spend some time learning how the language works, and you would quickly see that what you're doing is weird and unnecessary. I should add that this is not something new that happens. We see newbies do this every day. You'll be doing yourself a favour if you learn the right way.

Comment: What's with the (*) and (^) in your code? use comments if you need to... comment about what the code does inside the code.

Comment: thanks ndugger that is why I am on here, I did not really want to come to a forum but after weeks of trying to solve this and getting nowhere, I decided to ask others but do not know what I am doing wrong to do it the right way

Comment: Why is there an object just randomly in your code? you didn't assign it to anything or do anything with it.

Comment: Is this code placed inside of a `[ ... ]` and you're expecting it to populate that array? that's... not how this works...

Comment: I have split the string variation_type = item.split('_');   so for example the string is monday_0800 so variation_type[0] would be monday and variation_type[1] would be 0800 is that not correct then?

Comment: Oh are you meaning the arrays within variations?  ie. variations: [
                 {
                     regular_price: '19.99', ...... that is how woocommerce API says to do it? https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product

Comment: @Martiniboy, can you post what would be the value of `array[0]` ?

Comment: Array[0] would be something like monday_0800

Comment: I can't believe after all that critcism no one could point me in the right direction, I am not asking for the answer although it would have been nice :) just somebody to tell me what I am doing wrong in laymans terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below defines the array `variation` to be later used in `data`.

```
var teacher_ids = $( '#teacher_ids' ).val();
var status = 'pending';
var array = teacher_ids.split(','); 

variation=[];                   // Declare an empty array
                                // Then define it
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    variation_type = array[i].split('_');

    variation[i] = {
      regular_price: half_hour,
        attributes: [{
          id:3,
          slug: 'pa_lessonduration',
          //name: 'lessonduration',
          option: '1-hour'
        },{
          id: 1,
          slug: 'pa_weekday',
          //  name: 'weekday',
          option: variation_type[0]
        },{
          id: 2,
          slug: 'pa_daytime',
          //name: 'daytime',
          option: variation_type[1]
        }]
    }
}


var data = {                    // Define data
    name: title,
    short_description: excerpt,
    description: content,
    status: status,
    type: 'variable',
    variations : variation      // This is the array defined in the loop above
}

$.ajax({
    method: "PUT",
    url: POST_SUBMITTER.root + 'wc/v1/products/'+ product_id +'',
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', POST_SUBMITTER.nonce );
    },
    success : function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
        alert( POST_SUBMITTER.success );
    },
    fail : function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
        alert( POST_SUBMITTER.failure );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much **Louys Patrice Bessette**, I just needed declare an empty array of variation_type before the loop and it worked great, why did that not work with $.each?  In one of my previous tests I had tried to define a variation prior to adding it in the data var but it did not work but used $.each

Comment: `$.each()` is useful to cycle through a collection of HTML elements. And this collection has to be specified in front of it. Ex: `$(".item").each(function(){ // do something on each element that has the class item }` To cycle through an array, a javascript `for` loop is best.